# Call JavaScript function from Twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

I'm working on a Symfony2 project and I want to call a JavaScript function and pass an array of JSON objects (which I get from a controller) from a Twig.

But a first, very simple test already failed, like:

*main.js:*

```
function helloWorld(name) {
   console.log("hello " + name);
}
```

linked to main.js in the *twig* and called the function:

```
<body>
    <script>helloWorld("world!")</script>

    {% block javascripts %}
        <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

which results in a ReferenceError:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined"

**What do I have to do differently to make this work?**

*EDIT: Thanks to the two who took the time to answer. The described twig actually consists of a bunch of nested twigs and the placement of the javascript include was based on the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#index-11), guess that's why I didn't see the obvious. Should have detected the problem myself when phrasing the question though....*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Invert the order of the functions:

```
<body>
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}

<script>helloWorld("world!")</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

The script with the definition of the `helloWorld` definition is put *after* the function is executed. This means JavaScript doesn't yet know the function and triggers this error.

Solution: Put your javascript below your imports (before `</body>`, in the javascripts block for instance) or put the imports before the page javascript (in the head for instance).